# What is this error"ERROR: - unhandled Message: message.type=48"?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

hi i have been trying to integrate google play game services in my multiplayer game. i am using gpgs's unity sdk. I am following a Ray Wenderlich tutorial "Creating a Cross-Platform Multi-Player Game in Unity" on http://www.raywenderlich.com/87042/creating-cross-platform-multi-player-game-unity-part-2. As soon as i try to match two random player from two different ios devices. The setup gets stuck at 20% and i get this error in the log "ERROR: - unhandled Message: message.type=48". I will have you know that this worked once for me this morning but not before that and not after that. Someone please help before i blow my brains out

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=20603&start=10). "The way I fixed it was to basically go away for an hour and come back. At that point, the servers had cleared me out of any zombie rooms and I was ready to play again.".

Comment: Noticed the most recent comments on the blog you linked in your question all describe issues with this error 48.  Possible you are just using an outdated tutorial that no longer works?

Comment: yes i have but i have been at it since yesterday and it has worked only once and that too after 1 day

Comment: You probably saw this, but the google's said something about this hitting when using ios simulator and not real devices.  It's not that is it?

Comment: nope its not working on real device either